# How to make a div go over another div when clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these 2 divs and when I click on div 1 I want it to go over the second div, and if I click on Div 1 again I want it to go back to its original position (I want Div 1 to increase its width so it goes over the second Div). Here is my code where I have my 2 divs next to each other. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this? Thanks a lot in advance!

**NOTE:**
- No jQuery please. I'm trying to accomplish this with javascript and css.

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
}
#narrow {
  width: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
}
#wide {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wide">Div 1</div>
  <div id="narrow">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're getting hammered here because you haven't included any JavaScript that you've tried. It reads as, "Here's what I need, now go and do it for me."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to ditch `flex`, you can use a combination of `float` , `postion:absolute` and `transition` so that the main div "slides over" the other div

```js
document.querySelector("#wide").onclick = toggleWidth;

function toggleWidth() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
}

#narrow {
  width: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  float: right;
}

#wide {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  transition: width 2s;
}

#wide.active {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wide">Div 1</div>
  <div id="narrow">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

Note: Changing the opacity is purely optional, I've only done it to further illustrate the "slide over" effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
}
#narrow {
  width: 20vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(80vw - 10px);
  background: lightblue;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
#wide {
  width: calc(80vw - 10px); 
  background: lightgreen;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
}
.wider {
  width: 100vw!important;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wide" onclick="myFunction()">Div 1</div>
  <div id="narrow">Div 2</div>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("wide");
  element.classList.toggle("wider");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using JavaScript.
First, you prepare your CSS:

```
#narrow {
  width: 200px;
  transition: 0.32s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#wide.fullwidth ~ #narrow {
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Then, the JavaScript, like this:

```
document.querySelector("#wide").onclick = changeDivWidth;

var wideFull = false;

function changeDivWidth () {
   if (!wideFull) {
     this.classList.add("fullwidth");
     wideFull = true;
     return; // if variable wideFull is false, function stops here
   }
   wideFull = false;
   this.classList.remove("fullwidth");
}
```

Shorter approach using toggle();

```
document.querySelector("#wide").onclick = changeDivWidth;

function changeDivWidth () {
     this.classList.toggle("fullwidth");
}
```

Comment: you are overcomplicating this .. simply use `toggle` of classList

Comment: I just tried to make it easier to read for him, since I consider knowing the basics very important. Added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLtn2sz3/9/) ?

**JavaScript (Pure) :**

```
function HideDivOne(){
  var wide = document.getElementById("wide");
  var narrow = document.getElementById("narrow");

  if (wide.style.width == "70%"){
    wide.style.width = "100%";
    narrow.style.width = "0%";
    narrow.style.opacity = "0";
  }
  else{
    wide.style.width = "70%";
    narrow.style.width = "30%";
    narrow.style.opacity = "1";

  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
display: flex;
}
#narrow {
  width: 30%;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 20px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
#wide {
  width: 70%;
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 20px;
  transition: 0.2s;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wide" onclick="HideDivOne()">Div1</div>
  <div id="narrow" onclick="HideDivTwo()">Div2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the z-index of the divs based on your desired effect. My suggestion is using jQuery. On click on div 1 add a class to the div that modify the zindex, that is, if the class is not already added, if so, remove it.

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery for this